# Ubuntu 21.10 network connection stopped

Tags: networking, apache2, 21.10

I have two machines, both running ubuntu 21.10.  This notebook connects to router via wifi and is working fine.  My desktop, also running 21.10 worked fine last evening and runs on a wired connection.  Started it this morning, and no network connection, therefore packagekitd is stalling, and therefore I can not do apt update, or anything else. I just checked and if I boot the same machine using an Ubuntu 21.10 boot disk, it finds the wired connection and works fine.  The only difference I can find in the settings is a slightly different address for IPV6. Is this related to the recent apache/java security problem?

Any suggestions how to diagnose/fix the problem?
Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

As usual, was a very simple fix but just guesswork.  It appears something to do with vodafone dns server has changed overnight?  Same wired settings as have used for many years suddenly failed.  Fix was in network manager, wired, identity, settings had to explicitly select the mac address for my onboard ethernet card.  Never had to select it before, but having done so it all works fine.